# How to automatically enable line numbers in gvim netrw

Tags: vim, netrw

In my *.vimrc* file located in my home directory, I have already added `set nu` and every time I open a file in gvim, I get line numbers displayed at the extreme left.

But whenever I open a folder in gvim using `:Vex` (vertical split and open explorer) or `:Te`(open a new tab with explorer) commands or for that matter open a directory using gvim, I don't see line numbers, in spite of having `set nu` in my *.vimrc* and I have to again do `:set nu` manually.

I am using cent os 7 and netrw 149 and vim 7.4

How to get line numbers always whenever I open explorer using netrw in gvim?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your vim directory is `~/.vim`, You could try adding

```
set nu
```

in **~/.vim/after/ftplugin/netrw.vim**

`ftplugin` files are loaded every time a buffer is opened with the corresponding filetype. In this case the filetype is `netrw` so the file is called `netrw.vim`. You can check the file type of any buffer with `:echo &filetype`.

Comment: Thanks for response. But, i don't find the files mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @KartikPodugu You will have to create them. The `~/.vim` directory is your home directory where you can place custom configuration and initialisation options.

Try `:help VIMINIT` for more info